# Qt: Handle 'Save Print Output As' dialog with QPainter::begin()

Tags: qt, pdf, qpainter, qprinter

here is a minimal reproducable example of my problem:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QtPrintSupport/QPrinter>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPrinter printer;
    QPainter painter;

    // this will open a file dialog to save a pdf file
    if (!painter.begin(&printer)) {
        qDebug() << "how to get the difference between 'Dialog Canceled' and 'File in use' here?";

    }
    else {
        //do the painting stuf...
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

My question is - as already mentioned in the code - how do I know if the dialog is canceled by the user or the pdf file is just in use (for example opened in Adobe Reader)?

I already tried to check the `printer.outputFormat()` and the `printer.docName()` but they are both empty.

Comment: I wonder that  the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html#isValid) of `QPrinter::isValid()` says _To detect other failures check the output of QPainter::begin()_ while it returns bool  ... and not quite clear how to check that

Comment: Oh wow... As printing something seems to be a very common thing to me, maybe I'm doing something totally wrong? My normal use case is, that someone prints to a real printer, for which I have a QPrintDialog. But if he chooses something like 'Microsoft Print to PDF' there and prints, the QPrintDialog will be closed and I will reach that file dialog to choose the pdf file. 
Maybe there is a way to catch the selected file from the dialog to check on my own? But how, I dont even know where this dialogs comes from exactly :(